# get difference between 2 dates in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the difference between the 2 dates in googlescript. However it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone seem to know why? My user defined variables are working it's just when i get the difference between the 2 the result is like 4.28E8 whereas the answer is supposed to be like 40. Is there a way to convert the date into a number then convert it back into a date?

```
 ddate = output.getRange(lRow2,2,1,1).getValue() - output.getRange(2,1,1,1).getValue()
```

Comment: When you subtract two dates you get the difference in ms. 4.28E8 ms =  119 hours.

Comment: Search for posts like this:  [stackoverflow - javascript - difference between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: oh ok. so just convert it to hours. Thanks, @SpiderPig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function works, its just the difference is in milliseconds. For those interested in the conversion, it's as follows:

`diff = ((output.getRange(lRow2,2,1,1).getValue() - output.getRange(2,1,1,1).getValue()) / (1000*60*60*24))`

or simply:

`days = milliseconds/ (1000*60*60*24)`